# Hide and show list with button

Tags: html, css

So I have an unordered list with some list-items. I want to show and hide the nth-child of the list-item by using a button.

I tried using :hover over the button but it wont respond. Is this because its a button?
Take a look at the code. CSS:

```
div#right-column-sidebar {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 840px; 
    right: -140px
}
div#right-column-sidebar ol {
    position:absolute; 
    right: 150px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: red;
    list-style-type:none
}
div#right-column-sidebar ol li { 
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted grey; 
    width: 200px; 
    display: block;
}
div#right-column-sidebar ol li:nth-child(11) {
    visibility:hidden
}

a.button {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    no-repeat scroll top right;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px; /* sliding doors padding */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.button span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
}

a.button:hover div#right-column-sidebar ol li:nth-child(11){visibility:visible} {}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="right-column-sidebar">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#">Title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 20</a></li>
    </ol> 
    <a class="button" href="#"><span>Show more</span></a>
</div>
```

I am willing to try some jS as well and It would be nice to add a loading effect

Comment: You want an onclick javascript even that hides the list on click and trigger that.

Comment: I would like to avoid jS if possible. Using visibility:hidden / visible instead when hovering over the button

Comment: If you consider JS / jQUery: http://jsfiddle.net/cy4f3/

Comment: Your `a.button` styling is wrong: `border: 1px solid lightgrey;no-repeat scroll top right;`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery (as the others have suggested) you can do something as simple as this

```
$('#nth_item_button').click( function() { $('ul#my_ul li:nth-child(3)').toggle(); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS can only hide show child and sibling elements using `:hover`. Your HTML structure does not support this. You will need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Look up jQuery's .click(), .each(), and .eq() methods. jQuery is really easy to use, cross-browser compatible and you can look at their effects page and play around with all sorts of stuff (fading, sliding, etc.).

jQuery.com